# fire fox 57.0.1 (64-bit) hangs when accessing paypal on windows 7

Tags: firefox, paypal

I am working on a charity website which receives donations via paypal. Just the standard donation form button. It works fine on chrome, IE, Safari, Opera, but seems to be hanging in Firefox latest version. You click the button get the revolving 'please wait' message but in FF it never takes you to the actual paypal donation screen. Just seems to be firefox with the issue.

I have used firefox for years but have to admit the latest version 57.0.1 on windows 7 seems really buggy. No paypal pages work on it. Even the w3c and other sites hang.

So I performed a firefox reset/refresh from inside firefox control panel. To my amazement after rebooting the donation page finally worked. Thought I had solved issue. But then I closed/re-opened FF to perform same test and again it freezes on 'Please wait' screen.

Then I uninstalled FF completely, re-downloaded/installed - again the donation screen worked first time but not the second. Can't really give exact URL because its private client work but any paypal checkout seems to hang in latest version of FF. My client gets same issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're neither PayPal, nor firefox, support. You should contact one of them for help.

Answer (score 0):

There does appear to be a clash with some anti-virus software and the latest release of Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-startup-crash-g-data-security-software

I would suggest whitelisting the Firefox application in your AV software if necessary until firefox address the issue.